# Meaning of であるだけ in Naomi by Tanizaki

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

I'm reading the book 痴人の愛 https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/001383/files/58093_62049.html. I don't understand what であるだけ means in the following sentence

> 私はなるべく彼女の趣味を啓発するように、ちょっとした買い物をするのにも自分一人では決めないで、彼女の意見をいわせるようにし、彼女の頭から出る考えを出来るだけ採用したものですが、もともと箪笥だの長火鉢だのというような、在り来たりの世帯道具は置き所のない家**であるだけ**、従って選択も自由であり、どうでも自分等の好きなように意匠を施せるのでした。

My attempt at translation:

In order to educate her concerning her interests, even when little shopping I did not decide by myself but I let her to express her opinion and I adapted as much as possibly ideas from her head. (?) house where there is no place to put common household tools such as chests and braziers, accordingly we were free to choose and we were able to apply designs as we desired.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The uses of である](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/68581/the-uses-of-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b)

Comment: This is just である (attributive form of だ・です), followed by the ordinary particle だけ.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55065/meaning-of-x%e3%81%b0x%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91y-vs-x%e3%81%b0x%e3%81%bb%e3%81%a9y

Comment: @Karl, いいえ。。。なるとさんの回答の通り、「だけに」って意味で使われていて、[明鏡国語辞典](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/%E6%98%8E%E9%8F%A1%E5%9B%BD%E8%AA%9E%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/exact/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%AB) の❶の意味です。 "All the more because..." "as expected"　[jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%AB%20%23sentences) の26の例文中、この意味の「だけに」が使われているのは、「敵対勢力間の和平交渉再開だけに、関係は危うい。」と「火星は地球とよく似ているだけにひとしお興味をひく。」の２文のみですね。例文少ないですね。

Answer (score 2):

This だけ is the same as [だけに](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%88%E3%81%AB) or [だけあって](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6). This contraction(?) is not very common, but it does happen occasionally.

> 在り来たりの世帯道具は置き所のない家である**だけ(に)**、従って選択も自由であり、…
>
> As (our house) is a house where there is no place to put common household tools, accordingly, we were free to choose, ...
>
> As one might imagine from a house with no place to put...

Similar examples:

- 彼は若いだけ(に)、体力がある。
- この家は駅に近いだけ(に)家賃も高い。

Comment: 『痴人の愛』ページ内検索したら、この意味の「（である）だけ」（いずれも「に」なし）が他にも使われてますね。「...しかし表面が君子である**だけ** 、心の中はなかなか油断なく...」「云わば[襤褸]{ぼろ}に包まれた白さである**だけ** 、余計私を惹きつけました。」

Comment: @Chocolate 順接にも逆接にも使ってるんですね…。その前者の例は特に "all the more" 感があり、「だけあって」とはちょっと違う感じがします。